# How many zeros in the binary form of $1...x$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a(x)$ be the [A001511](https://oeis.org/A001511) sequence.

$$1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5...$$

> $a(n)−1$ is the number of trailing zeros in the binary expansion of $n$

How to calculate $f(x)$ that is the sum of $a(x)$?

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{x} a(n) $$

Comment: What kind of answer are you after? And have you looked through that OEIS page? Look at the one line that contains the word "asymptotic", for instance.

Comment: @markvs Of course, calculating the first, say, ten sums and entering that into OEIS is also a decent approach.

Comment: @Arthur I want to find the ratio between the natural numbers and $f(x)$

Comment: @IlyaGazman Well, that is _definitely_ answered in your own OEIS link in the one line that contains the word "asymptotic" (ctrl-f, or cmd-f on mac, is your friend here).

Comment: It is! Thank you!